# How to change the code so the upload progress is being displayed for every file when uploading multiple files at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup an uploader, which can upload multiple files at once and currently shows you the progress of  file being upload. I would like to show the progress of every file... Can someone help met out please?

```
<script>
function uploadFile() {
    var file = _("file").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progress").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + Number(event.loaded/1024/1024).toFixed(2) + " MB of " + Number(event.total/1024/1024).toFixed(2) + " MB - " + Math.round(percent) + "%";
}
</script>

<form class='upload' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' id='file' onchange='uploadFile()' multiple>
    <p id='uploader'><u>Drag</u> your files here or <u>click</u> in this area</p>
    <progress id='progress' value='0' max='100'></progress>
    <p id='status'></p>
    <button style='display: none;' class='hidden' type='submit' id='submit' name='submit'></button>
</form>
```

**07/05/2019: SOLVED! :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the array of files to `Promise` using `reduce` method of array, for this I've created another method in your code `uploadFiles` just call this method to upload every file one by one and see the progress of every file

```html
<script>
  var _ = (id) => document.getElementById(id)

  function uploadFile(file) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

      var formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("file", file);
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var showProgress = function(event) {
        if (event.loaded === event.total) {
          resolve()
        }

        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        _("progress").value = Math.round(percent);
        _("status").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + Number(event.loaded / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + " MB of " + Number(event.total / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + " MB - " + Math.round(percent) + "%";
      }
      ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", showProgress, false);
      ajax.open("POST", "");
      ajax.send(formdata);

      console.log(window.location)

    })
  }

  function uploadFiles() {
    var files = Array.from(_("file").files);
    files.reduce(function(a, file) {
      return a.then(function() {
        return uploadFile(file)
      })
    }, Promise.resolve(null))
  }
</script>


<form class='upload' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='file' name='file[]' id='file' onchange='uploadFiles()' multiple>
  <p id='uploader'><u>Drag</u> your files here or <u>click</u> in this area</p>
  <progress id='progress' value='0' max='100'></progress>
  <p id='status'></p>
  <button style='display: none;' class='hidden' type='submit' id='submit' name='submit'></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't work. If I try to upload two files, the progress bar now says: uploaded 0mb out of 0mb - 0%

Comment: Now try this one

Comment: Thanks again for your help - Your edit didn't work either I am afraid, still got 0mb out of 0mb. The progressbar is at 100% already at the start.

Comment: `event` argument was missing, please try again

Comment: are you testing with the correct url for ajax request?

Comment: Good news, now I am seeing progress again.. Still only for one file, but we are getting closer. I am testing with the correct url.

Comment: but tell me one thing, do all of the files are uploading successfully?

Comment: if the files are uploading, then try with the files of two different and big sizes to see the progress correctly

Comment: Yes they do upload and I tried with two different sizes, but no luck with that. Still showing the progress of one file only.

Comment: Any more ideas Shridhar Sharma?

Comment: Actually, can you please create a fiddle for your code, so I can test it by myself?

Comment: Forgot to add `return` inside `reduce` method. I've updated my answer and also updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m506dqto/

Comment: Correct, it does work perfectly! Thank you so much Shridhar Sharma.